# Is element#id necessary in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Recently I saw this on a CSS beginner's book (Beginning CSS Web Development By Simon Collison, Page 19)

```
h1#title{color:red;}
```

It is a `element#id` structure.

But is this necessary? Since ID is unique in one html webpage, the `element` is not necessary.

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is this necessary?

It can be, it's entirely context dependent.

It's extremely common for the same CSS file to be included in multiple pages, in which case the id *isn't* guaranteed to be unique. One page may have `<h1 id="title">` and another page might have `<div id="title">`, and you may only want to target one or the other.

It's up to you to decide if being more specific than `#id` is warranted.

Comment: +1 perfect *in which case the id isn't guaranteed to be unique*

Answer (score 5):

`id` are unique, but that doesn't mean they cannot be applied to other elements on different documents, so using something like `#title` can be used ONLY ONE in one document, but can be used for other element in another document so though `id`'s are unique, you can use it on different elements on different documents. So using `h1#title` will force the CSS to only apply on `h1` element having `id` `#title`.

Also, specificity matters, `h1#title` is more specific than `#title` so using something like

```
#title {
   color: red;
}
```

VS

```
h1#title {
   color: green; 
   /* This will be picked regardless of their order in the stylesheet */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. But, still this might be handy, when the programmer doesn't want to apply these  styles, if someone changes `h1` to some other tag like `p` or `h2` in html.